# How to setup different Scala versions on the same machine?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.10, scala-3

I want to follow the book on Scala[1] but it uses Scala 3 and I have Scala 2 installed. I want to use both the versions, something on the lines of `python2` and `python3`.

I tried installing Scala3 on my local using the [official source](https://dotty.epfl.ch/) but I could only grasp the project-level working directory. The `sbt` prompt does not work like a REPL would and I can only open REPL using Scala 2 (I checked the version everytime).

How do I open the REPL of Scala3 given I cannot uninstall Scala2?

Comment: You do not even need a system-wide installation of anything, **sbt** is just a bash script and it will download and configure the environment of each project, including the **sbt** version used by that project _(as well as the meta-project)_ the **Scala** version _(or versions for when cross-sompiling)_ of the project and the libraries of your project.

Comment: So, how do I run the REPL for Scala 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The sbt prompt does not work like a REPL

If you execute `sbt console` from within project directory it will drop you into REPL version corresponding to the project's `scalaVersion`. For example, executing `sbt console` within project created with `sbt new lampepfl/dotty.g8` would start Scala 3 REPL.

> but I could only grasp the project-level working directory

For system-wide installation first [install coursier](https://get-coursier.io/docs/cli-installation) and then execute `cs install scala3-repl`. This will install Scala 3 REPL alongside the Scala 2 one. Now Scala 3 REPL can be started with `scala3-repl` command whilst Scala 2 REPL simply with `scala` command.

Comment: This worked! I installed scala3-repl using cs and ran the command `scala3-repl` and it worked. I also verified by running this code that would throw error in Scala2: `def max(x: Int, y: Int) = if x > y then x else y`. Let me know if I can improve the question to display the intent more accurately. Thanks again!