# How to execute a Scala3 script when system has both Scala2 and Scala3 installed?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scala-3

I want to execute a following script using Scala3:

```
@main def m() =
  println("Hello, world! I'm a script")
```

When I type the command, `scala hello.scala`, I get the following error:

```
/Users/avirals/dev/learning-scala/hello-world/hello.scala:1: error: not found: type main
@main def m() =
 ^
one error found
```

I think it is because I have both the versions of Scala installed (2 and 3). I know how to start a REPL for both (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67392922/10834788)) but I am not able to execute a Scala3 script from the command line.

## [Update]

I tried `scala3-repl hello.scala` and it just opens the REPL:

```
➜  learning-scala git:(main) scala3-repl hello.scala
scala> m()
1 |m()
  |^
  |Not found: m
```

How do I execute a Scala 3 script from the command line given I have two different versions (2 and 3) of Scala installed?

My OS: MacOS

## Update 2

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67409786/10834788) answer, I tried running with `amm` and it worked for a few scripts. However, the following script failed:

### Script:

```
@main def m(args: String*) =
  var i = 0
  while i < args.length do
    println(args(i))
    i += 1
```

Error:

```
➜  learning-scala git:(main) amm printargs.scala
printargs.scala:2:3 expected (If | While | Try | DoWhile | For | Throw | Return | ImplicitLambda | SmallerExprOrLambda)
  var i = 0
  ^
```

Running the above script in a Scala3-REPL works:

```
➜  learning-scala git:(main) scala3-repl
scala> @main def m(args: String*) =
     |   var i = 0
     |   while i < args.length do
     |     println(args(i))
     |     i += 1
     |
def m(args: String*): Unit

scala> m("aviral", "srivastava")
aviral
srivastava
```

Running the same script in a system (MacOS) that has only Scala3 installed works just fine as well.

Comment: What is the "system"? If you are trying to find out how to execute specific programs on your system, you should consult the documentation for that system.  What is it, windows, macos, some linux distro? How is it even a scala question?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I updated the OS, it is MacOS.

Comment: @jwvh I updated the answer, it does not work.

Comment: https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists currently [Minimal scripting support #11379](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/11379). I was able to get it working by manually downloading a release from https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/releases/download/3.0.0-RC3/scala3-3.0.0-RC3.zip, unzipping, and giving executable permission to launchers

```
./scala3-3.0.0-RC3/bin/scala hello.scala
Hello, world! I'm a script
```

With `scala3-repl` launcher you could at least do

```
$ scala3-repl
scala> :load hello.scala                                                                                                                                                                                      
def m(): Unit

scala> m()                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Hello, world! I'm a script
```

Comment: Why did it work? How did `amm` figure out Scala 3 is needed here? I did not specify anything pertaining to Scala versions anywhere.
Thanks!

Comment: @AviralSrivastava Sorry ammonite currently does not work but you can subscribe to the open pull request https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/Ammonite/pull/1150 and watch progress.

Comment: No, it did work for a bit but then failed for complex scripts ( scripts involving functions and for loops and stuff).